# How to Synchronize File operation using java? Synchronized or Lock?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, readwritelock, reentrantreadwritelock

I created a application for reading and writing to a remote location property file using JSCH  library.

I want to synchronize the write operation .

This is my code ,

```
class WebApp{
    private String webappName;
    private boolean isQA = false;
    private String path ;

    public WebApp(String name , String  path , boolean isQA){
        this.webappName = name;
        this.path = path;
        this.isQA  = isQA;
    }
    public String getWebappName() {
        return webappName;
    }
    public void setWebappName(String webappName) {
        this.webappName = webappName;
    }
    public boolean isQA() {
        return isQA;
    }
    public void setQA(boolean isQA) {
        this.isQA = isQA;
    }
    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }
    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }
}

class WebAppProperty implements Runnable{

    private WebApp webapp; // webapp-1
    private String propertyFile; // server.properties
    private String keyValue;

    public String getPropertyFile() {
        return propertyFile;
    }
    public void setPropertyFile(String propertyFile) {
        this.propertyFile = propertyFile;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        writeToPropertyFile();
    }
    public WebAppProperty(WebApp webapp , String propertyFile,String keyValue){
        this.webapp  = webapp;
        this.propertyFile = propertyFile;
        this.keyValue = keyValue;

    }
    
    private void writeToPropertyFile(){
        try{
            // code  for writing key value pair into remote file
        }catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

}
```

This is what i want

- If a user try to write into to a property file on web app say 'A', all other user who try to write into the same file of same webapp should  wait , but another user can write into another files of same web app or file with same name on another webapp .

  Will the synchronized method can do all these works ? how it identify the webapp and property file ?

Do we need to synchronize both read and write operations ?

How to implement Lock on this scenario?

Note : i had seen different questions regarding concurrency , but those are not cleared my doubts that's why am asking new question, please help me to get clarifications on this

Comment: No. `synchronized` won't help. You choose approach which limits your options. Only way I see is "lock" files. You should check that special file exists, and if it doesn't create it, modify your property files and delete "lock" file.

Comment: @talex I have checked the lock implementation , just what am confusing is like how to lock the write operations on the same file only? Means if a thread try to write to file A no other thread can write to file A , but it should able to write to other files than file A. How it can possible by using Lock? What I understood is that we can lock the operation we performing

Comment: @AnsarSamad could you share part where you create WebAppProperty instances and run it?

Answer (score 0):

Write the Webapp class as follows:

```
class final WebApp{
private final String webappName;
private final boolean isQA = false;
private final String path ;

public WebApp(String name , String  path , boolean isQA){
    this.webappName = name;
    this.path = path;
    this.isQA  = isQA;
}
public String getWebappName() {
    return webappName;
}

public boolean isQA() {
    return isQA;
}

public String getPath() {
    return path;
}
```

}

Write your webappProperty class as follows:

```
class final WebAppProperty implements Runnable{

private final WebApp webapp; // webapp-1
private  finalString propertyFile; // server.properties
private final String keyValue;

public String getPropertyFile() {
    return propertyFile;
}    

@Override
public void run(){
    writeToPropertyFile();
}
public WebAppProperty(WebApp webapp , String propertyFile,String keyValue){
    this.webapp  = webapp;
    this.propertyFile = propertyFile;
    this.keyValue = keyValue;

}

private void writeToPropertyFile(){
    try{
        // code  for writing key value pair into remote file
    }catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

}

You don't need to use synchronized if you use this approach. Both the classes are immutable classes. Immutable references can be shared freely without any synchronization in a multithreaded environment.This is so because once an immutable is created it is frozen for the life of the object. Any changes that you need on the object can only happen by creating new objects.

Note that if you don't create immutable classes as described above you'll have to use synchronized in all the methods in the webapp class because you will need to protect shared mutable state in whichever method you touch it. Ditto for the second class.

Comment: Could you please tell me that how it allow one thread to allow write to file A.properties and same time block other thread to write into same file but allow them to write to other files?